Certain inequality of a non-decreasing function
I have a following strange inequality showing up. Let $F: (0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a non-decreasing function with the following two properties:
(i) $F(\sqrt{ad}) \leq \sqrt{F(a) F(d)}$, for all $a,d>0$;
(ii)\begin{equation} [F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) - F(d) F(\sqrt{ah})]^{2} \leq [F(a)F(d) - F(\sqrt{ad})^{2}] [F(d)F(h) - F(\sqrt{dh})^{2}], \end{equation} for all $a,d,h>0$. Then is it true that
\begin{equation} [F(b)F(e) - F(d) F(c)]^{2} \leq [F(a)F(d) - F(\sqrt{ad})^{2}] [F(d)F(h) - F(\sqrt{dh})^{2}], \end{equation} where $b\leq \sqrt{ad}$, $e\leq \sqrt{dh}$, $c\leq \sqrt{ah}$, and $(be-cd)^2\leq (ad-b^2)(dh-e^2)$.
Edit: I have tried the following
$0\leq [F(b)F(e) - F(d) F(c)]^{2}$ is same as saying $4F(b)F(e)F(d) F(c)\leq [F(b)F(e) + F(d) F(c)]^{2}$. By above properties,
\begin{align}4F(b)F(e)F(d) F(c)\leq [F(b)F(e) + F(d) F(c)]^{2} \leq [F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) + F(d) F(\sqrt{ah})]^{2} = F(\sqrt{ad})^2 F(\sqrt{dh})^2 + F(d)^2 F(\sqrt{ah})^2 + 2 F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) F(d) F(\sqrt{ah}) \end{align}
Thus,
\begin{equation} 
[F(b)F(e) - F(d) F(c)]^{2} \leq F(\sqrt{ad})^2 F(\sqrt{dh})^2 + F(d)^2 F(\sqrt{ah})^2 + 2 F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) F(d) F(\sqrt{ah}) - 4F(b)F(e)F(d) F(c) = [F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) - F(d) F(\sqrt{ah})]^{2} + 4P,
\end{equation}
where $P = F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh})F(\sqrt{ah})F(d) - F(b)F(c)F(e)F(d)$ is non-negative by monotonicity of $F$. Now using this,
\begin{align} [F(a)F(d) - F(\sqrt{ad})^{2}] [F(d)F(h) - F(\sqrt{dh})^{2}] - [F(\sqrt{ad})F(\sqrt{dh}) - F(d) F(\sqrt{ah})]^{2} - 4P \leq [F(a)F(d) - F(\sqrt{ad})^{2}] [F(d)F(h) - F(\sqrt{dh})^{2}] - [F(b)F(e) - F(d) F(c)]^{2}.
\end{align}
But this is not enough to conclude the result!
Any help is appreciated.

Please include what you tried

If $G(A)=\log (F(e^A))$ then $G$ is non decreasing and from i), is such that $$G(\frac{A+B}{2})\leq \frac{1}{2}(G(A)+G(B)).$$ I think that is enough to garantee that $G$ is convex on $R$ in particular to have $F$ continuous. May be it is useful to translate all these complicated conditions on $F$ in terms of $A,\ldots, H=\log h$ and in terms of $F_1(A)=F(e^A)=e^{G(A)}$.

Just in case it could help, what is the source of this problem?
